# how to filteri by asterisk or similar expression by rsync in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, rsync, wildcards

I have a lot of files named like:

```
/var/log/foo/2014-07-06-01.log
...
/var/log/foo/2014-07-20-04.log
```

Everyday I have several log files and I want to download specified day's log files:

```
$ rsync server:/var/log/foo/2014-07-06-*.log .
```

BUt I got `zsh: no matches found` error.

I found in the manual that I can filter by extension, but I couldn't find how to filter file name in case like this.

Is there easy way to use filtering with `rsync`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters, e.g.

```
$ rsync server:/var/log/foo/2014-07-06-\*.log .
```

or

```
$ rsync 'server:/var/log/foo/2014-07-06-*.log' .
```

Or better, install `url-quote-magic`, e.g.

```
autoload -Uz url-quote-magic
zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
zstyle ':urlglobber' url-other-schema http https ftp mailto
```

so that zsh will automatically do this for you. You may want to add other URL schemes...

EDIT: Alternatively, you can `unsetopt NOMATCH`, so that an error falls back to POSIX shell behavior, but I would discourage you to do that, because it could lead to unexpected results in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
$ noglob rsync server:/var/log/foo/2014-07-06-*.log .
```

From `zsh` man page:

```
noglob   Filename  generation  (globbing)  is not performed on any of the
         words.
```